# How do I eliminate the cut path on top and bottom of letters? See below

Tags: inkscape, text, svg, path

My design in Inkscape I'm trying to eliminate the cut paths on the top and bottoms of the letters.  [image: Hello Cut out]

So that it will look something like this type of card cutout
[image: example card]

Comment: Hi Tracy, Welcome to GDSE. Are you going to use a cutting machine for this?

Comment: Yes, I am using a Cricut Explorer Air to cut this.  I've been able to export svg files from Inkscape into Cricut Design successfully on other projects.  But just cannot seem to figure out this one.... (I'm a newbie to Inkscape; but have watched over 30 files).

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the text and do *Path > Object to Path* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  This will convert the text to outlines.
2. Ungroup the the text <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. *Path > Union* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>. This will join up all the letters as one path.
4. Draw a rectangle over the text
5. Select both text and rectangle and do *Path > Intersection* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*

The result will be all outlines so that your cutter will work properly.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Billy Kerr!!!  I'm going to try this right now!!!

Comment: Bugger.  I just got the HELLO cut out (truncated the top and bottom) but it actually cut the whole letter out.  Was hoping for the "cut path" to stop at the top and bottom, and skip to the next letter......

Comment: Did you miss out step 3, Path > Union?  Or perhaps you need to move the letters together so that they overlap, and will actually join up - so that the cutout will be one piece.

Comment: Ah!  I think the latter, maybe they need to join up; as I did Path>Union.  I did try it with a rectangle and star, but used: Path, Cut Path option and that worked just fine.  I'll keep messing around with it.

Comment: After a second look at your example, it looks like a popup image. Is that right?  You may have to go about this a different way. Let me think about it and I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: I think I found an answer!  Stand by, I'm going to try it on the cutting machine now!  I'm utilizing cut path after I convert everything to Object to Path, and I'm using the break apart feature too.  Then I grouped some added lines through Bezier (to serve as score lines)... Trial #3

Comment: It worked!  The small sample I went to worked!  I'm going to itemize each step so I don't forget and post.

Comment: @Tracy - great!!  Glad you found an answer.